# Using nested nodes from mutation payload to update local store

Tags: relayjs

Let's say I have a typical todo application. There's a `CreateTodo` mutation that takes a string and returns `CreateTodoPayload` with the newly created edge. The schema looks like this:

```
type Todo implements Node {
  id: String!
  content: String!
  user: User!
}

type User implements Node {
  id: String!
  todos: [Todo]
}

input CreateTodoInput {
  clientMutationId: String!
  content: String!
}

type CreateTodoPayload {
  clientMutationId: String!
  todo: Todo
}
```

How can I specify that this mutation will update the `user` node via `todo` using `FIELDS_CHANGE`? `fieldIDs` requires me to specify an immediate field on the payload, so I can make it work by also returning the user, but that seems counter to what Relay is trying to accomplish.

Similarly with `NODE_DELETE`, `RANGE_ADD` and `RANGE_DELETE` (even though this example doesn't use connections), `parentName` is a string for a field name on the payload and it seems one cannot specify a nested field, i.e., `todo.user`.

Comment: Why would a simple RANGE_ADD with user as parent not work for you here ?

Comment: @XuoriG it would if there was a way to specify the parent using some sort of a path syntax, perhaps "todo.user" or ["todo", "user"], but as far as I know, there isn't. Relay requires the parent to be directly on the payload which in effect couples the frontend and backend code.

Comment: and why isn't user directly on the payload here ? Your payload should probably return something like `{ clientMutationId: String, newTodoEdge: Todo, user: User}` no ?

Comment: @XuoriG it can be, but my question really is why it has to be. It's just clumsy having to specify every parent on the payload object itself when they're available via some path.